# How informal can 为 someone 服务 be？

Tags: grammar

Recently, I've heard the phrase " 为你们服务 “  used in a number of contexts. It seems like a relatively formal phrase, but I'm wondering how widely it could be used. Could I say, for example,
"我们一下车就有两个人为我们服务“ 
(the example would be at a sporting event with volunteers). 
Is this colloquial? Or would it only work in written, very formal language?

Answer (score 3):

This totally works colloquially.

One of the most famous slogans in Chinese is: 为人民服务 (Serve the people!) - there is not a single Chinese person who doesn't know this.

Likewise you can always 为 XXX 服务, this should be very easily understood by almost anyone.

edit: maybe it would just sound a *little* pedantic...you wouldn't exactly say that there's two people *serving* you in English, though, would you...

Answer (score 2):

or

我們一下車就有兩個人服務我們.

or better

我們一下車就有兩個人招待我們.

or more specifically

一下車便有兩個服務員招待我們.

(And I think the leading "我們" can be omitted.)

(Question: is "就有" proper spoken Mandarin?)

Comment: 就有 is fine in spoken Mandarin

Comment: 我們一下車就有兩個人服務我們.As a native speaker, I will never say like that. I would rather use 我们一下车就有两个人为我们服务。

Comment: @Xiage, how about "我們一下車就有兩個人招待我們."

Comment: @Xiage, it is sad to know that we adopt such clumsy sentence structure as the norm ......

Answer (score 1):

The phrase 为 someone 服务 (wèi shéi fúwù) means "to serve someone." It is a formal phrase that is typically used in business or government settings. It can also be used in more informal settings, such as when a customer is being served by a waiter or waitress.

The phrase 为你们服务 (wèi nǐmen fúwù) is a more polite and formal way of saying "I am here to serve you." It is typically used by people in customer service or other service-oriented roles.

In your example, "我们一下车就有两个人为我们服务" (wǒmen yīxià chē jiù yǒu liǎng ge rén wèi wǒmen fúwù), it is perfectly acceptable to use the phrase 为我们服务. This is because you are talking about a situation where you are being served by someone. The phrase 为我们服务 is a polite and formal way of saying that you are being served.

However, it is important to note that the phrase 为我们服务 is not always appropriate. For example, you would not use this phrase if you were talking to a friend or family member. In these situations, it would be more appropriate to use a more casual phrase, such as "我来帮你" (wǒ lái bāng nǐ) or "我可以帮忙吗？" (wǒ kěyǐ bāngmáng ma？).

Here are some other examples of how the phrase 为我们服务 can be used:

- "我们很高兴为您服务" (wǒmen hěn gāo xìng wèi nín fúwù) - "We are happy to serve you."
- "请问您需要什么服务？" (qǐngwèn nín xūyào shénme fúwù) - "Can I help you with anything?"
- "我会尽力为您服务" (wǒ huì jìnlì wèi nín fúwù) - "I will do my best to serve you."

Answer (score 0):

为 someone 服务 is a very formal expression and is usually used in written media. In daily life, people prefer to use **帮助** or just **帮**. For example,

(1) To offer a service, you would say, "先生，您需要**帮助**吗？".

(2) To request a service, you would say, "先生，您能**帮**我拿这个箱子吗？".

Sometimes, **服务** means a list of options a business could be able to offer. For examples, "先生，除了整理房间，您还需要什么其他服务吗？"